# not selector not assigning to img inside child div

Tags: css, css-selectors, less

I have some general style rules applied to the images on my website, for example:

`border: 5px solid red;`

I then want to style some of the `<img>` tags differently,

However inside a div in the page I don't want the `<img>` tags to pick up this extra styling, I'm trying to use the `not` selector like so:

HTML

```
<div class="no-overflow">
    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/rem/128.jpg">

  <div class="comment-ctrl">
    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/rem/128.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

LESS

```
.no-overflow:not(.comment-ctrl) {
 img { border: 5px solid green; }
}
```

This styling just ends up being applied to all `<img>` tags, the `not` selector seems to be ignored. I have been testing in this codepen:

http://codepen.io/JoeHastings/pen/MYrVWK

Is there some CSS syntax that would make this work without changing the DOM itself?

Comment: Are you missing a space in the selector? Should it not be `.no-overflow :not(.comment-ctrl)` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would probably be easier to use this

```
.no-overflow > img {
    border: 5px solid green;
}
```

That way it only selects images that are a direct descendant of the class name and won't select images inside other elements.